# Sending mass emails in the background with wp_mail & wp cron

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I want to send mass emails with wp_mail and wp cron in the background.

I tried the following code, it's sending emails but I have a few problems:

1. Currently I have 900+ emails in the array, the page keeps loading until it's finished the job instead of echoing Success and doing the job in the background, shouldn't it run in the background if the function is in wp cron?
2. I can't see the cron which created with `wp_schedule_single_event` in Scheduled Actions (I'm using [Advanced Cron Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-cron-manager/) plugin for checking the cron jobs. It's like the function is executed but the cron job isn't created(?)

   ```
   set_time_limit(0);
   function send_newsletter()
   {
       $i = 0;
       foreach ($emails as $email)
       {
           $i++;

           if ($i < count($emails))
           {
               sleep(60);
               wp_mail($email, $subject, $msg, $headers);
               continue;

            }else{
               break;
            }
       }

   }

   $args = array( false );

   if (!wp_next_scheduled('subscribers_newsletter')) {

       wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 10, 'subscribers_newsletter', $args );

       add_action( 'subscribers_newsletter', 'send_newsletter' );
       do_action( 'subscribers_newsletter' );

   }else{
        echo "Wait until the previous job finished";
   }
   ```

Comment: This is like a spam bot. I would assume wp_mail module does some type of checking. Mailchimp or similar services do this for you.

Comment: Well, there was a check so can't send more than the emails count. I edited the code. also I configured the wp_,mail to use our SMTP and DKIM, SPF, DMARC headers are passed in all of the sent emails headers.

Comment: With WP cron you are only scheduling a function to be called (maybe) at some point in the future. No data or state or anything, including your array of emails, will be automatically preserved, you need to do that yourself. A common method is to stash data in transients, if you are okay with it being potentially deleted by something else, otherwise you'll need to figure out a more persistent location (database, disk, etc.)

Comment: Having done this for a very long time, and being someone that has sent legitimate bulk commercial email, I would strongly recommend not sending from your web server. Even if it is 100% legit (which I'm not doubting), ISPs and/or users might still consider it UCBE and your server's IP could be blocked, which means your password reset or system notification emails might not get to users, either.